# Channel flow send suspend behavior

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

With the following code sample:

```
    val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)

    val flow = channelFlow {
        println("1")
        send("1")
        println("2")
        send("2")
    }.buffer(0)

    scope.launch {
        flow.collect {
            println("collect $it")
            delay(5000)
        }
    }
```

The following output:

```
1
2 // should be printed after collect 1
collect 1
collect 2 // after 5000ms
```

Expected:
the print 1, then print collect 1, wait 5 seconds, then print 2

it seem that the send function does not suspend, with a buffer set to 0 or RENDEZVOUS, using a standard flow with emit suspend work as expected, is there another operator, or does the channel flow can suspend(have a buffer with 0/1 capacity) ?

Comment: Why do you expect "2" to be printed after 5s? At the time you enter `collect {}` block, `send(1)` can be already resumed. I expect there is a race condition between "2" and "collect 1". In practice, it could be deterministic depending on coroutines internals.

Comment: i expect 2 to be printed after 5s because just before, the call send("1") is expected to suspend until collect finish(after the delay), it's work like this in a standard flow with emit(), or are you saying that send() will not suspend until the collect block finish ?

Comment: "send("1") is expected to suspend until collect finish" - no, it suspends until the start of collecting. It's not an equivalent of `emit()`.

Comment: ok, i see, thanks for the info, so there is no way to make it act like a standard flow(suspend until the whole collect block end) ?

Comment: I believe we use `channeFlow()` and `buffer()` mostly to allow running the producer and consumer concurrently. So why do you use these functions if you actually prefer "normal" flows?

Comment: for multithreading for example, and also for having the ability to choose between those behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the documentation of [Flow.buffer()](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/buffer.html) states, this function creates two coroutines: one producer and one consumer. These coroutines work concurrently. That means that at the time `collect()` block is launched to process an item, `send()` on the other side is already resumed. I believe there is a race condition between `2` and `collect 1`, but in practice the order may be deterministic.

"Normal" flow with `emit()` works differently. It works sequentially, so the producer and the consumer don't run at the same time. `emit()` suspends until the consumer finishes working on the previous item and requests another one.

Comment: using RENDEZVOUS buffer mode should make no buffer, so it should suspend ? but just until entering collect as you stated, choosing the buffer mode allow to modify the behavior

Comment: Yes, `send()` suspends, but it is resumed at the time the consumer picks the item. So at the time we start executing `collect()` block. If you add `3` to your example, you will see it will show up after 5s. This is because it is waiting at `send(2)` while the consumer is occupied processing the `1` item (in `delay()`). When consumer finishes and starst consuming `2`, producer is already resumed and print `3`.

Comment: ok i see, i expected that send() resume after collect() finish, there should be others solution, thanks

Comment: also, if i put the println("collect $it") and delay(5000) in onEach() before collect(), it should not have reached collect() at this point, i guess internally it resume before

Comment: I think you have some misconceptions on how this all works. Think of a `buffer()` as some kind of a "barrier" in the operators chain. It divides the chain into the producer chain above it and consumer chain below it and handles passing of items between them. `RENDEZVOUS` works by "pairing" the producer and the consumer, so they have to meet at the barrier at the same time to pass the item directly. Then they can again work concurrently: consumer consumes the item, producer produces the next one.

Comment: yes i see for the buffer and for RENDEZVOUS, and yes internally it use specific behavior that would explain why, it is designed as it, i have looked at https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/kotlinx-coroutines-core/common/src/channels/AbstractChannel.kt#L190 this is maybe one of the place where it suspend, there should be others solutions to use as this one has been designed this way, using channel, thanks

Comment: also, since it is divided into two coroutine, the seconds could not suspend the first, to achieve this behavior it would require somethings else

Comment: with further testing, yes with RENDEZVOUS printing 3 will not be printed before 2 is fully consumed(collect completed), but i think we should not think about collect(),
this is in the documentation of send()
"..suspending the caller while the buffer of this channel is full.."
in others words, to make send suspend, it is not a matter of collect() complete or not, it is a matter of if the buffer is full or not, so after send("1") the buffer is full and other send will suspend 5s as expected, it seem the buffer is full because collect() has a delay(), thanks

Comment: This is why I speak about producers and consumers. Anything above `buffer()` is producer and anything below it is a consumer. It doesn't matter if we place `delay()` in `collect {}` or in `onEach {}` - they both consume items from `buffer()`. We can also use e.g. `filter()` and then there will be more `send()` than calls to `collect()` body. In such case `filter()` would be a consumer from the `buffer()` perspective and a producer from the `collect()` perspective.

Comment: ok i see, it helped to understand better this operator not very used until now, thanks